# Regex to match specific strings followed by 6 digits

Tags: python, regex

Let say I have those 4 strings:

```
str1 = "license 123456"
str2 = "address 123456"
str3 = "license number 1234567"
str4 = "license num 1234"
```

I'm trying to match all the strings that have either `"permit"|"license"|"license number"|license num"` followed by exactly 6 digits.

I've tried this expression :

```
re.search(r"(permit|license|license number|license num)\d{6}$", str)
```

From what I understood, it was suppose to match my criteria, but it apparently also matches string with more than 6 digits (it doesn't match strings with less than 6).

How could I fix my regex expression ?

Comment: `\b(?:permit|address|license|license number|license num)\s+\d{6}$` does match 6-digit numbers after the specified words. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TcMdnj/1).

Comment: `\d{6}` itself matches exactly 6 digits, but those 6 digits can be a prefix of a longer string of digits. Consider what `foo\d{6}x` would match: `foo123456x`, but not `foo1234567x`.

Comment: @chepner hence the `$` to indicate end of string. `\d{6}$` should only match six digits followed by end of text.

Comment: You might want to put a `\W+` between the string and the digits for whitespace. But other than that it works as expected when I tested it.

Comment: Can you [edit] and give example data for correct and incorrect matches as well as output? I agree with other commenters that your regex *should* work (except for the whitespace, as others have pointed out).

Comment: You are only matching strings where the 6 digits are at the very end of the string, because the $ character at the end of the regular expression matches the end of the string. To fix the issue, you can modify it to this: r"(permit|license( number| num)?)[^\d]*(\d{6})\b"

Comment: Offtopic but don't call a variable `str`. It's the name of the string class in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly "license"|"license number"|license num" is a logic redundancy and can be shrunk to "license" itself.

secondly you are not specifying the pattern of characters that can be present between our license and numbers. this can be done by .*
so the main pattern becomes "permit|license.*[0-9]{6}$"

so the end code can be seen as below

```
str1 = "license 123456"
str2 = "address 123456"
str3 = "license number 1234567"
str4 = "license num 1234"
str_lst=[str1,str2,str3,str4]
import re
for i in str_lst:
    try:
        print(re.search("(permit|license)[^0-9]*[0-9]{6}$", i).string)
    except AttributeError :
        print('not matching')
```

Comment: This also matches for example `permit 123`

Comment: Can be forced by isolating or condition for filtering <6digits case and for >6digit case we can explicitly specifying non numeric characters between permit/license  word and last 6 digits. i have also edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

I think this may work:

```
^(permit|license|license number|license num)\s\d{6}$
```

or this, depends on how you search:

```
\b(permit|license|license number|license num)\s\d{6}\b
```